# php interactive shell returns without new line

Tags: php, command-line

As you can see in the image, `php -a` returns the response in the same line `php >`. Is there any way I can fix the problem?

[image]

```
php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo "Hi there";
Hi therephp >
```

PHP version is 5.4.24.

Comment: That is correct behavior. You need to append new line. `echo "Hi there\n";`

Comment: Add a line return at the end of your echo statement?

Comment: No better idea actually than modifying C source. (btw. annoys me too!) That's why I'm always using `var_dump()`, it inserts itself the newline at the end.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it with PHP 5.3.10, but can reproduce it with PHP 5.5.9

Comment: @hek2mgl that is, because behaviour changed. I need to look at the source quickly... hang on.

Comment: @hek2mgl https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/6c734a6b4c9ecf90162cf53fcf5f89864ccabbde#diff-43cd40d427070a1355f39a283ae22ac7L1231 this line didn't reappear later... seems like a break in 5.4, I'll ping Johannes about that.

Comment: @bwoebi Yeah this should be fixed! Thx for your efforts to make PHP better!

Comment: @MathewFoscarini - it is not correct, it just makes sense. interactive mode was not designed to punish users for not adding an explicit newline at the end of their output. Bugs that mention this in their bug tracker reflect that this behavior is not intended.